# Windows eventlog and log file

Tags: windows, logging, shared-directory, logfile

How i can generate a log file which contains which user edited and which file in a shared folder. multiple users is having rights to read/write/delete, No .exe execution is happening.
Please help how i can create that kind of log file.

Comment: Please be more precise on the language..

Answer (score 0):

1. Turn on Object Access auditing using Local Security Policy (under Local Policies/Audit Policy) or ask Active Directory administrator to configure this setting using a GPO.
2. Using Explorer, right click on the folder where you want auditing and select Security
3. Click Advanced button and then select Auditing Change Auditing tab
4. Click Add and add 'EveryOne' group
5. From the list of available entries, select Write/AppendData (and Delete, DeleteFolder)